# Recycler Item button's click only work on second click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one button in recyclerview adapter, when user will click on that, I want to maintain hide and show layout, now issue is that, it works only at second click, following is my code

```
holder.notification_rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {


                        if(flag==true)
                        {
                            holder.iv_arrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.down);
                            holder.notification_iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.notification_sub_text.setSingleLine(true);
                            holder.notification_sub_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                            int n = 1; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                            holder.notification_sub_text.setLines(n);
                            flag = false;
                        }
                        else if(flag==false)
                        {
                            holder.iv_arrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.up);
                            holder.notification_sub_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.notification_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.notification_sub_text.setSingleLine(false);
                            int n = 2; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                            holder.notification_sub_text.setLines(n);
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: just a suggestion why use if ..else if loop for boolean value ... its true or false.

Comment: Don't use boolean instead of that can use `if(view.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: i guess you `flag` default value is `false` and your views are visible or vice versa

Comment: @RakeshKumar can you provide answer?

Comment: @khimji, I have already provided an answer above. What is the issue with that?

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to manage visibility with boolean.it will definitely work but it will make things more complex. other than that you can manage that by checking view visibility in a better way.

Initially, hide your sub layout by putting `holder.notification_iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in your onBindViewHolder method or you can manage through XML also.

```
holder.notification_rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if(holder.notification_iv.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    {
                        holder.iv_arrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.down);
                        holder.notification_iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.notification_sub_text.setSingleLine(true);
                        holder.notification_sub_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                        int n = 1; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                        holder.notification_sub_text.setLines(n);
                    }
                    else
                     {
                        holder.iv_arrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.up);
                        holder.notification_sub_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.notification_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.notification_sub_text.setSingleLine(false);
                        int n = 2; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                        holder.notification_sub_text.setLines(n);
                    }
                }
            });
```